# Global Menu Bar Gnome3

Tags: 14.04, gnome, globalmenu

Is there any way to get global menus in Ubuntu gnome like in unity? Or is there a way I could install the unity panel on the gnome shell?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:
As Unity was released after lots of people expected to see Gnome 3 on the next Ubuntu version, the compatibility for Gnome 3 never was added.
You could try to do some experiments in getting Unity onto Gnome 3, but this may lead to some troubles as both, Unity and the Gnome Shell, are having a fixed unremovable top bar on the screen.
This problem is at least the one anybody can actually see. There will be  architectural problems as well.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation, note is in beta: https://gitlab.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu